# ExtJS Graph not rendering inside panel

Tags: extjs, extjs4

Graph:

```
var chart = Ext.create('Ext.chart.Chart', {  
    style: 'background:#fff',  
    animate: true,  
    shadow: true,  
    store: store1,  
    axes: [{  
        type: 'Numeric',  
        position: 'left',  
        fields: ['data1'],  
        label: {  
            renderer: Ext.util.Format.numberRenderer('0,0')  
        },  
        title: 'Number of Hits',  
        grid: true,  
        minimum: 0  
    }, {  
        type: 'Category',  
        position: 'bottom',  
        fields: ['name'],  
        title: 'Month of the Year'  
    }],
    series: [{  
        type: 'column',  
        axis: 'left',  
        highlight: true,  
        tips: {  
          trackMouse: true,  
          width: 140,  
          height: 28,  
          renderer: function(storeItem, item) {  
            this.setTitle(storeItem.get('name') + ': ' + storeItem.get('data1') + ' $');  
          }  
        },  
        label: {  
          display: 'insideEnd',  
          'text-anchor': 'middle',  
            field: 'data1',  
            renderer: Ext.util.Format.numberRenderer('0'),  
            orientation: 'vertical',  
            color: '#333'  
        },  
        xField: 'name',  
        yField: 'data1'  
    }]  
});
```

this not working.

```
{  
        xtype : 'panel',  
        layout : {  
            type : 'hbox',  
            pack : 'center'  
        },  
        id:'graphpanel',  
        width : 940,  
        margin : '20 0 20 0',  
        border : 0,  
        items: chart  
}
```

this working.

```
var win = Ext.create('Ext.window.Window', {  
    width: 800,  
    height: 600,  
    minHeight: 400,  
    minWidth: 550,  
    hidden: false,  
    maximizable: true,  
    title: 'Bar Chart',  
    autoShow: true,  
    layout: 'fit',  
    items: chart  
});
```

here is my problem graph working fine in popup window but not in panel. if i popup window first then only graph is rendering in panel.
pl'z help sorry for bad code formatting..:(

Comment: Formatting is not so difficult. To create code blocks or other preformatted text, indent by four spaces.
To create not a block, but an inline code span, use backticks.

Comment: @LorenzMeyer Thanks for code formatting ,could plz help to resolve this issue.

Comment: could you resolve my issue too? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65345785/ext-js-4-chart-inside-viewport

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not providing the chart with dimensions, either explicitly (giving it a width and height) or implicitly (by using an appropriate layout).

The panel layout should be `fit`. Also, be sure whatever is the parent of that panel is giving it a height.